# Please suggest some algorithm to find the node in a tree whose distance to its farthest node is minimum among all the nodes

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

Please suggest some algorithm to find the node in a tree whose distance to its farthest node is minimum among all the nodes.

Its is not a graph and it is not weighted.

Comment: You need to rephrase your question.

Comment: He doesn't it makes sense. He's essentially looking for the most "central" vertex in a graph (the node whose most distant node is minumum of all nodes).

Comment: Concerning the added "It is not a graph": A tree is a special case of graph, so graph algorithms should work for your tree, even if not maximally efficient.

Comment: Just a generic tree or a binary tree or some-tree else?

Comment: You need to revisit your understanding of the term "graph".  A tree is a graph.

Comment: The issue with trees (even non-weighted) is that there is no well-defined distance defined between siblings. Transform it into a equally connected graph, though, and the distance is certainly 2.

Answer (score 11):

Choose an arbitrary node *v* in the tree *T*.
Run BFS making *v* as the root of *T*.
BFS outputs the distances from *v* to all the other nodes of *T*.

Now choose a node *u* that is farthest from *v*.
Run again BFS making *u* as the root.
On the new distance output, find a node *w* that is farthest from *u*.

Consider the path between *u* and *w*.
This is the longest path in the tree *T*.
The node in the midle of the path is **the center** of the tree *T*.

Note that there may exist two centers in a tree. If so, they are neighbours.

Performance: *O(n)*, where *n* is the number of nodes of *T*.

### Proof

**Claim**: a leaf (*u*) that is furthest from *some* node *v* lies on the longest path.

If we prove it, then the algorithm is correct, since it first finds *u*, and, since it's one end of the longest path, uses DFS to find this path itself.

Proof of the **claim**:  Let's use retucto ad absurdum.  Assume *u---r* is the longest path in the tree; and for some node *v* neither *v---u*, nor *v---r* is the longest path from *v*.  Instead, the longest path is *v---k*.  We have two cases:

a) *u---r* and *v--k* have a common node *o*.  Then *v--o--u* and *v--o--r* are shorter than *u---o---k*.  Then *o---r* is shorter than *o---k*.  Then *u---o---r* is not the longest path in graph, because *u---o---k* is longer.  It contradicts our assumption.

b) *u---r* and *v--k* don't have common nodes.  But since the graph is connected, there are nodes *o1* and *o2* on each of these paths, such that the path between them *o1--o2* doesn't contain any other nodes on these two paths.  The contradiction to the assumption is the same as in point a), but with *o1--o2* instead of mere *o* (in fact, point *a* is just a special case of *b*, where *o1=o2*).

This proves the claim and hence the correctness of the algorithm.

(this is proof written by [Pavel Shved](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158676/pavel-shved), and the original author might have a shorter one).

Comment: Could you divulge some reasoning for your method of finding the longest path?

Answer (score 3):

Remove leaves. If more than 2 nodes left, repeat. The node (or 2 nodes) left will be the node you are looking for.

Why this works:

The node(s) are in the middle of the longest path `P` in the tree. Their max distance to any node is at most half of the length of the path (otherwise it would not be the longest one). Any other node on `P` will obviously have greater distance to the further end of `P` than the found node(s). Any node `n` not on `P` will have its furthest node at least (distance from `n` to the closest node on `P`, say `c`) + (distance from `c` to the further end of `P`), so again more than the node(s) found by the algorithm.

Comment: I dont know what is the root node so no idea what is the leaf node.

Comment: A leaf node will have exactly one edge.

Comment: this will always find the root node (asuming it has more than 1 edge, otherwise it will find the lowest branch above the root)

Comment: @jk: As I understand, the edges are undirected, so there is no 'root'. This always finds the middle of the longest path in the graph. A node that has only 1 edge is a leaf, so it will be removed in the first iteration.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Johnson's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson's_algorithm) for sparse graphs, but otherwise use the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd-Warshall_algorithm) simply because it is trivial to implement.

Essentially you want to find the distance from every node to every other node, and then just trivially search for the property you want.

Comment: Those algorithms are new to me, and do indeed appear simpler to code than Djikstra.

Comment: Note that FW is O(n^3) which may not be ideal.

Comment: Same as repeated Djikstra, for this application.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Dijkstra's algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) on each node in turn, to find all the distances from that node to every other node; scan the resulting list to get the distance to the farthest node. Once you've Dijkstra'd every node, another scan will give you the minimum of that maximal distances.

Dijkstra is usually regarded as having runtime `O(v^2)`, where v is the number of nodes; you'd be running it once per node, which will increase the time to `O(v^3)` in a naive implementation. You may be able to make gains by storing the results of earlier nodes' Dijkstra runs and using them as known values in later runs.

Comment: Floyd-Warshall is much simpler to code than Dijkstra's, but yes, it has the same complexity.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said in comments:
A tree is a graph - an undirected connected acyclic graph to be exact - see ["Tree" (Graph theory)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29).

Comment: A tree cannot be undirected, can it?

Comment: A tree has an implicit direction. Each node has a well-defined distance to the root node (tree not forest) and two connected nodes have distances to the root that differ by one. The node with the smaller distance to the root node is the parent; the node with the larger distance is the child. This parent-child relation in tree-shaped graphs is thus defined in pure graph terms. Furthermore, trees are acyclic graphs, so there is no other edge betwee parents and their childs. Hence, the parent-child relation of connected nodes acts as a direction of the edge.