# central point of a tree?

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

Suppose we have a rooted ordered tree. For each node, we have a linked list of children. P[i] is the sum of distances of node i to all other nodes. Is there an algorithm that we could find one of the nodes with minimal P[i] of the tree(might be several equal P[i]), that in worst case costs O(n) time?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking. Are you saying you want to find the minimum value of P[i] given the linked list of children, and the edge distances for this list? I'm just clarifying because I'm somewhat confused, sorry about that ^^

Comment: Also, since this is a tree, isn't there only path from one node to another? If this is the case, isn't P[i] the same for every node, since the distance from one node to every other node in the tree would be the same...? Still a bit confused, sorry about that...

Comment: sorry, @blahman, I am trying to find one of the nodes, not the value of P[i], I have edited the question.

Comment: No problems, though there's something I'm still not entirely sure about. An example of what would be "correct" here would be really helpful. Sorry about asking so many questions.

Comment: I'm almost certain the answer is yes

Comment: user22997, If there are any answers you like be sure to check them or upvote them.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some working O(N) code. In this example I use the graph {0:[1,2,3],1:[4,5],2:[6]}

I coded this up for fun. For the graph below it finds the centre is node 0 which has a P[i] value of 9. A mapping from i->P[i] is {0: 9, 1: 10, 2: 12, 3: 14, 4: 15, 5: 15, 6: 17}

```
nodes={0:[1,2,3],1:[4,5],2:[6]}
PB={}
NB={}
def below(i):
    if i not in nodes:
        PB[i]=0
        NB[i]=1
        return 0,1
    tot_nodes_below=0
    tot_paths_below=0
    for node in nodes[i]:
        paths_below,nodes_below=below(node)
        tot_nodes_below+=nodes_below
        tot_paths_below+=paths_below
    tot_paths_below+=tot_nodes_below
    tot_nodes_below+=1
    PB[i]=tot_paths_below
    NB[i]=tot_nodes_below
    return tot_paths_below,tot_nodes_below

P={0:below(0)[0]}
def fill_P(i):
    for node in nodes[i]:
        P[node]=P[i]+7-2*NB[node] #7 is the number of nodes
        if node in nodes:
            fill_P(node)
fill_P(0)

_min=min(P.values())
answers=[k for k in P if P[k]==_min]
print answers
"[0]"
```

Explanation:
This code is O(N) (i think right?)

Basically nodes = dict which shows each parent node connecting to its child nodes.

Let T[i] be "tree i". I define this as the subtree starting at node i. (e.g. T[2]=2:6,  while T[0] is the whole tree, T[1] would be 1:[4,5].)

now NB[i] is the number of nodes in T[i].

NB={0: 7, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1}

PB[i] is the sum of distances of nodes from i within T[i]. (so PB[i] would basically be P[i] except we are only looking at T[i] instead of T[0].

PB={0: 9, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0}

See PB[0]=9 because there are 9 paths going to 0 in T[0]. PB[6]=0 as NB[0]=1 etc.

So to actually build PB and NB we need the recursive O(N) function "below(i)".

below(i) starts at the root node and works its way down each subtree T[i]. For each subtree it works out NB[i] and PB[i]. Note the base case of the recursion is trivial, if the node has no child node, PB[i]=0 and NB[i]=1.

To work out PB[i] and NB[i] for a node that has child nodes, we use a recursive formula.
Let node i have child nodes x1..xj  then NB[i]=1+sum(NB[x]).

There is a similar recursive formula to work out PB[i].

PB[i]=SUM(PB[x])+NB[i]    the reason we add NB[i] is because each node below has to travel an extra distance 1 to get from the subtree T[x] to node i.

Once our function below(i) has populated NB and PB, we can use these two results to find out P.

fill_P(i) uses NB and PB to do just this.

The idea is that P[i] will be close to the value of P[j] if nodes i and j are near each other.

In fact lets see if we can work out P[1] using NB[1],PB[1] and P[0].

it turns out P[1]=P[0]+7-2*NB[1]
(we didn't even need to use results from PB, however we needed  PB to get the initial P[0] value).
to see why this formula is true, think about why P[1] isn't equal to P[0]. It helps to have a picture of the tree. Lets split the tree into two pieces by deleting node 1. Now this gives a left side of the tree (which doesn't include node 0) and a right side of the tree which does include node 0). note the left side of the tree is just T[1] and we have results NB[1] for this. P[1] is the same as P[0] apart from all paths from nodes in T[1] travel distance 1 less. All paths from nodes not in T[1] travel 1 further (going through node 0 to get to node 1). The number of paths is simply NB[1] and 7-NB[1] respectively. So we have P[1]=P[0]+(7-NB[1])-NB[1] which gives the formula we require.

Now we have correct P values for P[0] and P[1]. We can calculate values of any child of node 1 or node 0. fill_P just goes through each of the child nodes applying this formula and we are left with the result P. WE just iterate through P to find the minimum and that is our result..

Hopefully this makes sense now cheers.

Comment: Fixed. Let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: Sorry, @robert king, I don't quite get your algorithm, would you please explain your idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can compute P[i] for all nodes in time O(n) - including of course internal nodes, which will tend to be the ones with small P[i]. After this, finding the smallest P[i] is an additional O(n), so the sum is O(n).

Think in terms of sending messages between nodes. Start with an arbitrary node, which could be the root. To each neighbour of that node, send a request for info about nodes and total lengths. Receive a message from each neighbour giving the number of nodes in the subtree rooted at that neighbour, and the total distance of all nodes in that subtree to that neighbour.

From this work out P[i] for the root, and send each neighbour a message giving the number of nodes and total distance to the root in all of the tree except for the subtree rooted at that neighbour.

In each node not the originator, propagate the first message as a similar request to all neighbours except one sending in the request. Sum up the count of nodes. To each distance add the product of the count of nodes associated with it and the distance to the neighbour sending in the reply. Total up these sums to send back the response to the original request.

When you get a message back from the originator giving the sum of distances and counts for the whole tree except your subtree combine this with the info in the message you sent back to work out your P[i] and totals for the similar message that you send back to the nodes that you sent query messages to.

This ends up computing P[i] at all nodes. Each link between nodes sees only a small constant number of messages. Each message requires only a small constant amount of work (some subtotals need to be calculated as a group total - a small amount). So the cost is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

You only need for each node to find the distance to the node(s) furthest from it, NOT the sum. Those with shortest such distance will be the "center" of the tree.

For algorithms you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333506/please-suggest-some-algorithm-to-find-the-node-in-a-tree-whose-distance-to-its-f) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124566/binary-tree-longest-path-between-2-nodes)

[edit] Possible incomplete (or worse) answer when using sums:
Take {R:(a),a:(b,c),c:(d)} then you get the sums as follows:
R - 8
a - 5
b - 8
c - 6
d - 9
which clearly gives `a` as the central point
However when you the 'traditional method you get:
R-d 3
a-d 2
b-d 3
c-R|b 2
d-R|b 3
which gives `a` and `c` as central points
This shows at least one case where using the sums will result in an *incomplete* answer. This prompts the question if there is a case where the sums-method will give an *incorrect* answer.

Comment: That's how the [center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_center) is traditionally defined, but that's not the definition the asker is using (and the two are not compatible).

Comment: @Nick Barnes: It would be interesting to see if an answer that delivers the required result can do it in less than O(n^2)

Comment: @slashmais See my O(N) solution..  :)

Comment: @robert king: cool, I should have read it more carefully. PS I'm updating my answer with a possible caveat when using the sums.